# Can I install and run SharePoint Server 2007 or 2010 on Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7

Can I install and run SharePoint Server 2007 or 2010 on Windows 7 Professional?

Comment: assumably he has, there is no way 'out of the box' way, or obvious method to achieve this. It is a slightly obscure workaround for development only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  I've installed SP 2007 on vista, but it's the same steps on win7 too. http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx

Happy SharePoint-ing

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a little obscure (the method to do it) but perfectly feasible. I have my development machine setup with windows 7 enterprise and SP 2010 using this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx

It must be a x64 os though. Ask away if I can help with anything else. (I found it very slow at first, then upgraded from 4 to 8gb ram)